# Python Openpyxl - Merge_Cells()

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm was trying to use the merge_cells function, where I start at a non empty cell and merge everything to the next non empty cell.

In the example down below, I'm trying to find a way to merge on the **second row** the following:

-From column C to D

-From column E to I

-From column J to L

-From column M to Q

[image]

Using openpyxl function I can use either `ws.merge_cells('C2:D2')` or `ws.merge_cells(start_row=2, start_column=3, end_row=2, end_column=4)`

But my plan was to do this automatically, without knowing the exact cell coordinates.
Is there a way to find for example a way to select a "non empty cell" and go to the next "non empty cell", creating the range automatically?

Another interesting thing, is getting the limit of the last cell in the range. Starting from M2 and knowing when to stop. (Stop at Q2 & Not going until end of excel column limit)

Could anyone help me with the logic behind this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no magic here, you'll have to check the cells for values and merge accordingly.

Comment: Ah alright. Good to know! I'll just use a loop to check if cell.value is not none. Thanks Charlie!